# ruby on rails regular expression to remove html tags and its content from text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want regular expression in ruby on rails which remove all the html tags and its content from the given text.

For example if my text is :-INPUT :-

```
<span id="span_is"><br><br><u><i>Hi</i></u></span>
```

then it should display only OUTPUT should be as follows:-

```
Hi
```

in short i want regular expression or a function which remove <> and  whatever the content between <>.

Thanks & Regards,

Salil Gaikwad

Comment: I found a solution. I have posted the regex [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74196970/6734208)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your string is quite simple and that solution *might* work. However, you shouldn't reinvent the wheel. Rails already includes some powerful [sanitization helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html).

```
string = '<span id="span_is"><br><br><u><i>Hi</i></u></span>'
strip_tags(string)
```

Comment: just to add, it does not removes characters like &nbsp; :)

Answer (score 19):

```
'<span id="span_is"><br><br><u><i>Hi</i></u></span>'.gsub(/<\/?[^>]+>/, '')
```

Comment: Although the accepted answer is the most elegant way to go, this solution actually suits my needs better. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this. Please.

While your sample-input is fairly trivial, you mention that you want to use it in a lot broader scope.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

For Ruby, you can try using http://hpricot.com/ to parse HTML instead.

Comment: Actually i need to solve my problem that in my mail when i view as a text it shows html tags.So i replace my chat.text.plain.erb 
with following as answered by jimmy

<%= @chat.gsub(/<\/?[^>]+>/, '')  %> 


and it works for me .
anyways thanks for your comment.

Salil