# Regex - Match everything except HTML tags

Tags: php, regex

I've searched for this but couldn't find a solution that worked for me.
I need regex pattern that will match all text except html tags, so I can make it cyrilic (which would obviously ruin the entire html =))

So, for example:

```
<p>text1</p>
<p>text2 <span class="theClass">text3</span></p>
```

I need to match text1, text2, and text3, so something like

```
preg_match_all("/pattern/", $text, $matches)
```

and then I would just iterate over the matches, or if it can be done with preg_replace, to replace text1/2/3, with textA/B/C, that would be even better.

Comment: No. You can't. I don't even write "what did you try? Please share your attempts". You just can't parse HTML with RegEx. Seriously, no. Don't do it, it won't work. Don't even think about it. Funny reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1207195

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: "RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags" solution worked, since I don't need to parse completely arbitrary DOM structure, but only one with a few tags (p, span, strong, a). Thanks for answers.

Comment: It sounds like what you really want to do is strip out all the HTML tags, for which PHP has the built-in `strip_tags` function.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 4):

As you probably know, regex is not a great choice for this (the general advice here will be to use a Dom parser).

However, if you needed a quick regex solution, you use this (see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/bZ1gT7)):

```
<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|[^<]+
```

How this works is that on the left the `<[^>]*>` matches complete `<tags>`, then the `(*SKIP)(*F)` causes the regex to fail and the engine to advance to the position in the string that follows the last character of the matched tag.

This is an application of a general technique to [exclude patterns from matches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174) (read the linked question for more details).

If you don't want to allow the matches to span several lines, add `\r\n` to the negated character class that does your matching, like so:

```
<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|[^<\r\n]+
```

Comment: I used solution from Adriano Repetti's link which he posted in comments under my question.

Answer (score 1):

How about this RegEx:

```
/(?<=>)[\w\s]+(?=<)/g
```

**[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vB7sP1)**

Comment: Your pattern doesn't work.

Comment: @jovialcore can you please elaborate and present the scenario you think does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one (in Ruby):

```
/(?<!<)(?<!<\/)(?<![<\/\w+])([[:alpha:]])+(?!>)/
```

Enjoy !

Answer (score -3):

Please use PHP DOMDocument class to parse XML content :

[PHP Doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)