# Regex - syntax error javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

After reading this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244506/regex-match-everything-except-html-tags) I am trying to use this regex

> /(!<[^>]+>)+/g

Like this

```
var regex = /(!<[^>]+>)+/g;
new RegExp('myString', regex)
```

but I get

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor
>   '/(!<[^>]+>)+/g'

Anybody have idea how to use it right?

Comment: What are you doing? You already defined a regex in `regex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Regexp` is used when you have a regular expression in a *string* and you want to convert it to a regular expression object.

It is awful and you should almost never use it. (The exception is when you are dynamically generating a regex).

You don't need to use it: You created the object using a regular expression literal on the previous line.

---

To apply the regular expression to a string, use the `match` method:

```js
var regex = /(!<[^>]+>)+/g;
console.log("myString".match(regex));
console.log("Trivial !<tag> example".match(regex));
console.log("!<tag attribute='>>>'> example".match(regex));
```

(But [applying regex to HTML is usually a terrible idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)).

Answer (score 0):

`RegExp` is used to create regular expression from string

The second attribute should be flags like `i` , `g`, `m` but you're giving a regular expression itself.

The syntax of `RegExp` is `RegExp(regexString,flags)`

but you are using

```
var regex = /(!<[^>]+>)+/g;
new RegExp('myString', regex)
                       ^^^^^^
```

You can't use the `RegExp` function to test a string.

if you want to check `'myString'` against your regular expression, use `regex.test('myString')`

if you want to find all matches of the regex in `'myString'`, use `'myString'.match(regex)`

Comment: "That's the problem" — That's a symptom. The problem is that `new RegExp` is used to create regular expression objects, not to apply regular expression objects to strings.

Comment: agree. in first rev, I pointed out a big mistake in the question. Edited now