# PHP Regex that looks past <br> tags that may or may not be there

Tags: php, regex, regex-group

I am writing a regex that looks through html.  Sometimes there is a break tag or two in the middle of a sentence. I need to be able to grab all the sentence and ignore the 
 tags.

I have tried many versions of this. as you would expect this is a html email it is looking through, If I extend out the group to include the break tags then of course it captures them

```php
<div class=&quot;content-spacer&quot;[^>]*>[\r\s]*<p[^>]*>[\r\s]*<strong[^>]*>[^<]*<\/strong>[\r\s]*<\/p>[\r\s]*<p [^>]*>([^<]*)<br> <br> Thanks so much for your time! <br> Tammy <\/p>
```

I have tried variations of this regex.

the html I am looking through is this

```html
<tbody>
 <tr style=&quot;padding:0;vertical-align:top;text-align:left;&quot;> 
 <td style=&quot;word-break:break-word;-webkit-hyphens:auto;-moz-hyphens:auto;hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse;padding:0;vertical-align:top;text-align:left;color:rgb(102, 102, 102);font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-weight:normal;margin:0;line-height:28px;font-size:16px;&quot;> 
 <div class=&quot;content-spacer&quot; style=&quot;padding-bottom:20px;&quot;> 
 <p style=&quot;margin:10px 0;color:rgb(102, 102, 102);font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-weight:normal;padding:0;text-align:left;line-height:28px;font-size:16px;&quot;><strong style=&quot;color:rgb(51, 51, 51);&quot;> Message from Tammy Waring</strong></p> 
 <p style=&quot;margin:10px 0;color:rgb(102, 102, 102);font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-weight:normal;padding:0;text-align:left;line-height:28px;font-size:16px;&quot;> Hi there! I am looking for renting a cabin and was wondering if this cabin allows outside fires within a fire pit ? <br> <br> Thanks so much for your time! <br> Tammy </p> 
 </div>
```

I want it to grab the group at the end and ignore the br's 
I can either grab it all ending with Tammy's name or I can grab up to the first br tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: Also see [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2341603) on using a regex to parse HTML.

Comment: You could post process the result... text.replace(/<br>/g, "");

Comment: @Synthetx I don't actually have access to the code base. at this point, I only have access to an input field that takes in the regex. I will clarify that in original post thank you for your comment.

Comment: @LeviSmith Perhaps something like this can be adapted to your needs: <[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|[^<\r\n]+
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244506/regex-match-everything-except-html-tags

Answer (score 0):

Since you also tagged php using the [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function [may be a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14684106/4148878) because, as many people like to point out HTML is not really parseable by regex.